# Accordion tab auto open when clicking the anchor link

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I'd like to make the accordion tab auto open when clicking the anchor link, could you help me how to do that?

Below is the example code.
Thank you for the help!

**HTML**

```
<ol>
  <li><a href="#australia">Australia</a>
    <ol>
      <li><a href="#sydney">Sydney</a></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>


<button class="accordion">Trips</button>
                <div class="panel">
                  <h3>Visit <span id="australia">Australia</span></h3>
                  <p>More text...</p>
                </div>

<button class="accordion">Itinerary</button>
                <div class="panel">
                  <h3>Explore <span id="sydney">Sydney</span></h3>
                    <p>More text...</p>
                </div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.accordion').click(function(){

  if( $(this).hasClass('active') ){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).next().removeClass('show');
  }else{
    $('.accordion').removeClass('active');
    $('.panel').removeClass('show');

    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).next().addClass('show');
  }

})
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/a3uebzsc)

Comment: Do u use show/hide func of jquery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add in your script part following code (considered your current markup structure):

```
$("ol li a").click(function(){
    $($(this).attr('href')).closest('.panel').prev('.accordion').trigger('click')
    return false
});
```